# Несколько select'ов с уникальными значениями

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Есть форма с несколькими select. Набор option у всех одинаковый. Требуется сделать так, чтобы при выборе option одного select, другой select с таким же option:selected менялся на тот, который был в первом select до изменения. Сейчас это выглядит так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').focus(function() {
    getVal = $(this).val();
    $('#currentSel').val(getVal);
    arr = [];
    x = 0;
    $('.dropdown-toggle').each(function() {
      x++;
      arr[x] = $(this).val();
    });

  });

  $('.dropdown-toggle').change(function() {
    if ($.inArray($(this).val(), arr) > -1) {
      getVal = $('#currentSel').val();
      key_unsel = $.inArray($(this).val(), arr);
      key_sel = $.inArray(getVal, arr);
      $('select:eq(' + key_sel + ') option:selected[value=' + $('#currentSel').val() + ']').removeAttr('selected');
      $('select:eq(' + key_sel + ')').val(getVal);

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <select class="dropdown-toggle">
    <option value="email" selected="selected">email</option>
    <option value="phone">phone</option>
    <option value="name">name</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <select class="dropdown-toggle">
    <option value="email">email</option>
    <option value="phone" selected="selected">phone</option>
    <option value="name">name</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <select class="dropdown-toggle">
    <option value="email">email</option>
    <option value="phone">phone</option>
    <option value="name" selected="selected">name</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <input type="text" id="currentSel">
</div>
```

Срабатывает только в первый раз. Хотя, по присваиваемым значениям и ключам в консоль пишет все верно.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oldV;
  $('.dropdown-toggle').focus(function() {
    oldV = $(this).val();
    $('#currentSel').val(oldV);
  });

  $('.dropdown-toggle').change(function() {
    var newV = $(this).val();  
    $('.dropdown-toggle').not(this).each(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == newV)
        $(this).val(oldV);
    });
    $(this).blur(); // Без этого не будет вызова focus()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <select class="dropdown-toggle">
    <option value="email" selected="selected">email</option>
    <option value="phone">phone</option>
    <option value="name">name</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <select class="dropdown-toggle">
    <option value="email">email</option>
    <option value="phone" selected="selected">phone</option>
    <option value="name">name</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <select class="dropdown-toggle">
    <option value="email">email</option>
    <option value="phone">phone</option>
    <option value="name" selected="selected">name</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <input type="text" id="currentSel">
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! То, что нужно!